# Kentico 11+ WebForms PortalEngine and WebObjectActivator

Tags: dependency-injection, webforms, kentico

Has anyone had any success with setting a DI adapter to `HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator` on a Kentico 11 hotfix 24 WebForms PortalEngine website?

With https://www.nuget.org/packages/DependencyInjection.WebForms.Unity/ being added on Global.asax `Application_Start` any page/admin request is producing the following error for me:

```
[Exception: Only one page manager (CMSPageManager or CMSPortalManager) is allowed on the page.]
   CMS.PortalEngine.PortalContext.set_CurrentPageManager(IPageManager value) +90
   CMS.PortalEngine.Web.UI.CMSPortalManager..ctor() +210

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +328
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetResolverDelegate>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Constructor\ConstructorResolution.cs:79
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:162
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:162
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:162
   Unity.<>c__DisplayClass111_0.<OptimizingFactory>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\UnityContainer.Resolution.cs:271
   Unity.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Strategies\BuildPlanStrategy.cs:88
   Unity.<>c.<.ctor>b__73_2(BuilderStrategy[] chain, BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\UnityContainer.Resolution.cs:420
   Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(Type type, String name, InternalRegistration registration) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Builder\Context\BuilderContext.cs:177
   Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(Type type, String name) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Builder\Context\BuilderContext.cs:44
   Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(ParameterInfo parameter, Object value) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Builder\Context\BuilderContext.cs:217
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateParameterResolvers>b__0(BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Parameters\ParametersProcessor.cs:121
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetResolverDelegate>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Constructor\ConstructorResolution.cs:77
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:162
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:162
   Unity.Processors.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:162
   Unity.<>c__DisplayClass111_0.<OptimizingFactory>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\UnityContainer.Resolution.cs:271
   Unity.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Strategies\BuildPlanStrategy.cs:80
   Unity.<>c.<.ctor>b__73_1(BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\UnityContainer.Resolution.cs:361
   Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type type, String name, ResolverOverride[] overrides) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\UnityContainer.IUnityContainer.cs:244
   Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(IUnityContainer container, Type t, ResolverOverride[] overrides) in C:\projects\unity\Abstractions\src\Extensions\Container\UnityContainer.cs:913
   HouseofCat.DependencyInjection.WebForms.Unity.ContainerServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) in C:\GitHub\personal\HouseofCat.DependencyInjection.WebForms.Unity\ContainerServiceProvider.cs:49
   ASP.cmspages_portaltemplate_aspx.__BuildControlplcRoot() in C:\GIT\tests\KenticoTests\CMS\CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx:0
   ASP.cmspages_portaltemplate_aspx.__BuildControlform() in C:\GIT\tests\KenticoTests\CMS\CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx:13
   ASP.cmspages_portaltemplate_aspx.__BuildControlTree(cmspages_portaltemplate_aspx __ctrl) in C:\GIT\tests\KenticoTests\CMS\CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx:1
   ASP.cmspages_portaltemplate_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +48
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +76
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +24
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +62
   ASP.cmspages_portaltemplate_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +48
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +73
```

If I don't add the adapter I get no error, I can't really tell why the `PortalContext.CurrentPageManager` is already initialized for it to throw that error when the page/controls are being built up.

Any help getting to the bottom of it would be greatly appreciated.

### Update 1

[image]

Application_Start is just using this extension method: https://github.com/houseofcat/DependencyInjection.WebForms/blob/5bf89863f083eb4d0aebb65f0c3a9e06cfd633b5/src/DependencyInjection.WebForms.Unity/HttpApplicationExtensions.cs#L19 to add the container.

I haven't added any registrations yet, only the `IUnityContainer` is registered in the container.

Comment: Did you register any types in the container? Or is it happening even with an empty container?

Comment: can you show your global.asax code here?

Comment: Hi Dmitry and Peter question updated with a screenshot of the container registrations and the Application_Start code.

Comment: This works great with K12 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to use DI with `HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator` on Kentico, you'll need Kentico 12+.

Comment: I am on K12, but have the exact same issue. I had to downgrade all Unity packages to get it to work, because the Microsoft one does not throw this error, the HouseOfCat does. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get WebForms Dependency Injection working with Kentico 11.0.

Originally I installed Microsofts Nuget package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity/)

However,

> Due to a breaking change in Unity.Abstractions going from 3.3.1 to 4.0.0

mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebFormsDependencyInjection/issues/7) I had to switch to [DependencyInjection.WebForms.Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DependencyInjection.WebForms.Unity/)

After updating the CMSApp project to .NET 4.7.2 I thought I would be good to go but received errors when trying to run the application due to the dependencies not being inject.

Come to find out after updating the project to 4.7.2, within the web.config the `<compilation>` element was changed to 4.7.2 but the `<httpRuntime>` element was not. I manually updated it to 4.7.2 as well and everything started working!

[This](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/issues/727) Github issue helped guide me to the solution.